# What's the simplest security method of a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

It's running into an Intranet, .net framework 3.5, hosted in IIS 7.0 and it's using wsHttpBinding with null security. Now I have to protect it to allow only specific users can run it.

Seems that I should use SSL and certificates but I'd really like stay away of that because looks complex, basically I'm looking for the simplest way.

I took a look to netTcpBinding and seems to me this is the right way, if so, can you confirm if using net.tcp it would be able to be consumed by some asp.net site.

Any comments are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: The simplest could be that you specify the only valid user names allowed to connect in the web.config of the WCF web application, this only works if you trust nobody unauthorized will edit such web.config.

Comment: @DavidePiras, in this way, I have to enable windows authentication, if so not SSL is required, right?

Comment: @m0dest0: I think Davide is saying the usernames would be hard-coded into the config file.  Only people who know those credentials would be allowed access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have an intranet, which means that you have internal users. It depends where the call to the WCF service is coming from.

If we assume:

- Internal users, who login to a windows domain
- The client machines and the server are in the same domain
- The user runs a windows app on their machine, which makes the WCF call

Then the simplest solution is to use windows authentication

- The client makes the call in the security context of the logged on user
- The server checks the group membership of the user to determin if it should allow access

Answer (score 2):

You said you are using an Intranet app.

If so, you could turn on Windows Authentication, and allow only specific users in IIS (this is also controlled in the web.config). If everyone is on the intranet, it should authenticate automatically without users needing to enter a password or user name.

However, if anyone outside your intranet needs to reach this service, you'll need to include SSL & https to protect the credentials sent to the service.